# Como saber se constante tem um valor?

Tags: react-native

Tenho o código:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Tile, List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';

class UserDetail extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    title: '',
    phone: '',
  }
}

render() {
const { id, title, whatsapp, email, phone, login, location } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
//RECEBO A CONSTANTE ACIMA DA TELA ANTERIOR. ALGUNS ITENS VEM COM INFORMAÇÃO, OUTROS NÃO

if (title){
  this.setState({title: {title}});
}

if (phone){
  this.setState({phone: {phone}});
  //QUERO SABER SE A CONSTANTE ACIMA TEM INFORMAÇÃO, E ASSIM, USÁ-LA NO ESTADO CORRESPONDENTE, POIS QUANDO ESTÁ VAZIA DÁ ERRO
}

return (
  <ScrollView>
    <Tile
      imageSrc={{ uri: `https://buscafree.com.br/assets/img/items/${id}.jpg`}}
      featured
      title={title}
      //caption={email}
    />

    <List>
      <ListItem
        title="Endereço"
        rightTitle={this.state.title}
        hideChevron
      />
      <ListItem
        title="Endereço"
        rightTitle={this.state.phone} //USAREI AQUI
        hideChevron
      />
    </List>
  </ScrollView>
);
}
}

export default UserDetail;
```

Meu código recebe algumas informações da tela anterior. Porém, nem todos os itens tem um valor (no meu caso, o item PHONE às vezes vem com informação e às vezes não...)

Quando tento imprimi-lo na tela, dá erro caso ele esteja vazio/nulo.

Como faço pra verificar se o mesmo tem informação antes de imprimir na tela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta checar como voce esta fazendo. Mas voce nao deve usar `setState()` no metodo `render()` -- este mesmo so deve ter o papel de modelo pra visao, nada mais.

Entao voce deve mostrar uma interface de usuario pro caso que a variavel nao tenha nenhum valor. Por exemplo, se phone nao estiver setado, voce mostra uma mensagem dizendo algo como "nao ha valor de telefone definido".

Dai depois que o valor da variavel for definido (eu espero!) de alguma maneira, (e.g. clica um botao que faz um pedido http que no final seta o state do componente) o metodo render vai pular o "if" e ir diretamente pra visao desejada.

```
render() {
  if (!phone) {
    return <Text>Ainda nao ha informacoes do telefone. Carregando ...</Text>;
  }

  // se phone estiver definido, mostramos a visao desejada
  return (
    {/* Visao desejada */}
  );
}
```

Vale a pena indicar que voce nao precisa ometer toda a tela so por causa de uma variavel nao definida. Nesse caso, voce divide a interface em varios componentes de aprensentacao. Cada um desses componentes checa por si os valores da variavel que precisam pra apresentar a informacao. Se o valor ainda nao foi definido, cada componente mostra o seu proprio "spinner" como a mensagem de carregar.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. estou aprendendo react-native faz uns 20 dias, parece bem fácil, mas tem esses detalhes... pode explicar melhor porque nao devo usar setstate no render? o que quero é que, caso exista o phone, seja criada uma tag listitem com os dados. vou vendo se faço aqui. obrigado

Comment: Uma maneira de explicar isso é a "separação de conceitos". O papel do método `render()` é definir o modelo da interface de usuário. Somente isso. Como as coisas aparecem. O meio da interação e modificação da interface é separado da visão. A documentação oficial do React afirma: "The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify component state, it returns the same result each time it’s invoked, and it does not directly interact with the browser." https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render